# How to fix "ERESOLVE could not resolve" when deploying firebase functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, npm-install

When I deploy my firebase function with `firebase deploy --only functions:nextServer`, an error occurs as follows:

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.
i  functions: preparing . directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/tony/programming/options-outcry (87.22 MB) for uploading
✔  functions: . folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function nextServer(us-central1)...
Build failed: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/styles@5.10.3
npm ERR! Found: @types/react@18.0.17
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   dev @types/react@"18.0.17" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.95
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/base
npm ERR!     @mui/base@"5.0.0-alpha.95" from @mui/material@5.10.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"^5.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!   10 more (@mui/icons-material, @mui/material, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.10.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!   @mui/styles@"^5.9.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@17.0.49
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.10.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!     @mui/styles@"^5.9.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /www-data-home/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-09-04T21_53_24_874Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
```

I searched up how to fix `ERESOLVE` errors in general, and most answers tell me to add the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag to the `npm install` command.

However, the install that is happening here occurs within firebase functions' deployment process, and I have not found anything that allows me to add this flag (via `firebase.json` or any other method).

How can I fix this build error, which only occurs when I deploy to firebase?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by adding the npm flag inside the `"functions"` section of `firebase.json`:

```
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$PROJECT_DIR\" install --legacy-peer-deps",
      "npm --prefix \"$PROJECT_DIR\" run build --legacy-peer-deps"
    ],
    "runtime": "nodejs14"
  },
```